# Cannot read property 'contract' of undefined. Node api interacting with smart contract

Tags: web3js, contract-debugging, nodejs

Hi I'm trying to interact with an Ethereum smart contract from my node js api.

My controller function is as follows:

```
var web3 = require('web3');

module.exports.getTokenBalance = function(req, res) {
var abi = //long ABI
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi);

  // initiate contract for an address
  var myContractInstance = MyContract.at('...');
  myContractInstance.balanceOf.call('addr', function(err, data) {

  }
}
```

I'm using the `web3@0.20` package. When I try to call this API function I get the following error :

> "Cannot read property 'contract' of undefined."

Am I missing something stupid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`require('web3')` returns a class. You need to instantiate it first. Note the capital W:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://localhost:8545'));
// (or some other provider)

// web3.eth.contract should work down here.
```

Comment: Ok cool. Another thing is, I'd like to somehow have a Eth node running on a heroku server so I can send transactions there from my api. Is this a sensible thing to do?

Comment: Seems like an unrelated question, so it might be better to ask it as such. But I do want to make sure you're aware of existing public nodes like [Infura](https://infura.io).

Comment: What a fantastic resource. Thanks I'll take a look into it.